# windows 7 "system reserved" drive on ssd harddisk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

i just installed windows 7 on an ssd harddisk and i got a so called "system reserved" drive of 100MB

does anyone what that is for? and how i can get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This partition holds Windows Recovery Environment files as well as Bitlocker information and is created by default during the install of Windows 7.
There are ways to remove it during the install, but to do it afterwards is more complex and not risk-free. For a measly 100MB, I'm quite happy to leave it alone.

Comment: thanks! but it's strange. i have another win7 installation on a normal harddisk and i dont see this drive.

Comment: Is it the same version of Windows 7? The Home version doesn't have Bitlocker. Also, if your disk was already partitioned and formatted prior to installation then I think it won't create it.

Comment: Confirmed the latter myself now :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of Windows 7 (if not Windows Vista). It protects important boot files in an "invisible" partition, regardless if your HD is SSD or spinning disks. You cannot get rid of it, unless you choose another OS.